# How do I access the updated value of a observable variable from GetxController in main.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a HomeController like this

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  RxDouble latitude = 0.0.obs;
  
  //This is just an example because I don't want to make the code too long here.
//The latitude is being updated from the geolocator package.

update(double newLatitude) {
    latitude.value = newLatitude;
  }
}
```

and my main.dart file is like this

```
//1: Declared the HomeController instance as a global variable.
final HomeController homeController = Get.put(HomeController());

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeService();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
    ),
  );
  service.startService();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {

  //2: Used it to print like this
  print("Latitude: ${homeController.latitude.value}");

  });
}
```

I want to print the updated value of latitude inside the timer method in main.dart file.
How can I do that using getx i've tried to print like this 
1: Declared the HomeController instance as a global variable.
2: Used it to print like this

```
print("Latitude: ${homeController.latitude.value}");
```

But it's not printing the updated value.
I'm using [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) to handle the background task

Comment: That is the right way to print it. It just must mean that the value is not updated in the controller.